# Combine cells together in same column

Tags: excel, vba

Ok I've gone through a lot of the previous questions and can't find one that fits what I'm looking to do.

I'm trying to build a macro or VBA that will merge cells from Group 1 in a Column with cells from Group 2 in the same Column into other cells in the same Column.

I need the macro to be able to be done for every column on the sheet. To activate it for a column I want it to be when an "x" is put into the cell in that column in Row 72.

For Example:

```
I enter "x" in Cell 72 on Column MP.

I need Cell 78 in the MP column to merge cell 10 and 129 together with a " / " between them.
```

I know that formula `=MP78 & " / " &MP129`works and can copy and paste it but a formula wouldn't work when information can be over written in a cell.

Any help would be great.

I attached screen shots of the groups to show as well.

**Group 1**

[image: Group 1]

**Group 2**

[image: Group 2]

**Where to merge Cells

[image: Where to merge Cells]

Answer (score 0):

This is the response I prepared for your question yesterday. Please paste the code in the code module of the worksheet on which you want the action. It's a module created by Excel, not one you need to insert. The location is important.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Variatus @STO 26 Jan 2020

    ' list the cells that should trigger joining actions
    '   in their respective columns
    Const Triggers As String = "A4,B16, D15,MP72"

    ' list all cell you wish to merge in the Trigger column.
    '   Like, 30 = 6 & 23 to mean, merge the values of cell
    '                              6 & 23 in cell 30
    '   (separating commas are imporant, spaces are not)
    Const Mergers As String = "78=10&129, 30=6&23, 31=14 & 12, 32=30 & 18"

    Dim Trigger() As String
    Dim t As Integer
    Dim R As Long, C As Long
    Dim Merger() As String, Sp() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Trigger = Split(Triggers, ",")
    For t = 0 To UBound(Trigger)
        If Target.Address = Range(Trim(Trigger(t))).Address Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            C = Target.Column
            Merger = Split(Mergers, ",")
            For i = 0 To UBound(Merger)
                Sp = Split(Merger(i), "=")
                R = Val(Sp(0))
                Sp = Split(Sp(1), "&")
                Cells(R, C).Value = Cells(Val(Sp(0)), C).Value & _
                                    " / " & _
                                    Cells(Val(Sp(1)), C).Value
            Next i
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next t
End Sub
```

The procedure will respond to a double-click rather than entering "x" but it will take action only if particular cells are double-clicked. The `Const Triggers` lists the cells. I have included `MP72` in the list and other cells which I used for my testing. Remove them. You can specify just one cell or many. The code takes the column from the clicked cell. Only one of the choices will be executed on one double-click.

The `Const Mergers` allows you to specify the cells you want merged - always in the clicked column. The format is simple: "78 = 10 & 129" means "merge the values in cells in rows 10 and 129 in row 78. You can specify as many of such merges as you wish. My example has four, just to show how to enter the specs.

Comment: Keep Getting Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed

Comment: Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Variatus @STO 26 Jan 2020

    ' list the cells that should trigger joining actions
    '   in their respective columns
    Const Triggers As String = "72"

    ' list all cell you wish to merge in the Trigger column.
    '   Like, 30 = 6 & 23 to mean, merge the values of cell
    '                              6 & 23 in cell 30
    '   (separating commas are imporant, spaces are not)
    Const Mergers As String = "78=10&129, 79=11&130, 80=12&131, 82=14&133, 83=15&134,

Comment: It highlights this line on the debug   If Target.Address = Range(Trim(Trigger(t))).Address Then

Comment: You must specify the trigger cells by theiur full address, i.e. row & column, e.g. "MP72" instead of the mere "72" you have.

Comment: So if its every cell 72 from B to ZZZ I need to enter each one in the Const Triggers part?

Comment: One trigger cell will trigger all the changes in the column it specifies which are defined in the `Mergers` array. If the trigger is in column MP you can only specify changes in column MP.

Comment: That part makes since, but I was to set a trigger for each column to be the 72 cell for that column how would that work. It seems to be too many with all of them listed. +

Comment: If you want row 72 to be the trigger in many columns I could modify the code. However, that's a matter of convenience. For the existing code you can specify 255 trigger cells before I would have to ask you to test whether you might add more.

Comment: This worked perfectly for what we were looking at. Would it possible to have it do it for 400 total columns?                                                                     
            And second question I have is that when you double click in a different cell other then row 72 now to edit the contents of the cell it gives the following Visual Basic error "Run-time error '1004: Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed"

Comment: when you debug "If Target.Address = Range(Trim(Trigger(t))).Address Then" is yellow. Is there a way to still be able to double click in a different cell to edit the content without it giving the error?

Comment: Sorry about my slow response. I'm moving house. Yes, you could do this for 400 columns provided all of them require the same vertical merging of cell content. I can't reproduce your error. The posted code (which I tested now) allows double-clicking other cells. You may have made alterations? I suggest yiu ask your second question in a separate thread.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I come up with and it turns most of the ConstTriggers red

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Variatus @STO 26 Jan 2020

    ' list the cells that should trigger joining actions
    '   in their respective columns
    Const Triggers As String = "B72,C72,D72,E72,F72,G72,H72,I72,J72,K72,L72,M72,N72,O72,P72,Q72,R72,S72,T72,U72,V72,W72,X72,Y72,Z72,AA72,AB72,AC72,AD72,AE72,AF72,AG72,AH72,AI72,AJ72,AK72,AL72,AM72,AN72,AO72,AP72,AQ72,AR72,AS72,AT72,AU72,AV72,AW72,AX72,AY72,AZ72,BA72,BB72,BC72,BD72,BE72,BF72,BG72,BH72,BI72,BJ72,BK72,BL72,BM72,BN72,BO72,BP72,BQ72,BR72,BS72,BT72,BU72,BV72,BW72,BX72,BY72,BZ72,CA72,CB72,CC72,CD72,CE72,CF72,CG72,CH72,CI72,CJ72,CK72,CL72,CM72,CN72,CO72,CP72,CQ72,CR72,CS72,CT72,CU72,CV72,CW72,CX72,CY72,CZ72,DA72,DB72,DC72,DD72,DE72,DF72,DG72,DH72,DI72,DJ72,DK72,DL72,DM72,DN72,DO72,DP72,DQ72,DR72,DS72,DT72,DU72,DV72,DW72,DX72,DY72,DZ72,EA72,EB72,EC72,ED72,EE72,EF72,EG72,EH72,EI72,EJ72,EK72,EL72,EM72,EN72,EO72,EP72,EQ72,ER72,ES72,ET72,EU72,EV72,EW72,EX72,EY72,EZ72,FA72,FB72,FC72,FD72,FE72,FF72,FG72,FH72,FI72,FJ72,FK72,FL72,FM72,FN72,FO72,FP72,FQ72,FR72,FS72,FT72,HD72,HE72,HF72,HG72,HH72,HI72,HJ72,HK72,HL72,HM72,HN72,HO72,HP72,HQ72,HR72,HS72,HT72,HU72,HV72,HW72,HX72,HY72,HZ72,IA72,IB72,IC72,ID72,IE72,IF72,IG72,IH72,II72,IJ72,IK72,IL72,IM72,IN72,IO72,IP72,IQ72,IR72,IS72,IT72,IU72,IV72,IW72,IX72,IY72,IZ72,JA72,JB72,JC72,JD72,JE72,JF72,JG72,JH72,JI72,JJ72,JK72,JL72,JM72,JN72,JO72,JP72,JQ72,JR72,JS72,JT72,JU72,JV72,JW72,JX72,JY72,JZ72,KA72,KB72,KC72,KD72,KE72,KF72,KG72,KH72,KI72,KJ72,KK72,KL72,KM72,KN72,KO72,KP72,KQ72,KR72,KS72,KT72,KU72,KV72,KW72,KX72,KY72,KZ72,LA72,LB72,LC72,LD72,LE72,LF72,LG72,LH72,LI72,LJ72,LK72,LL72,LM72,LN72,LO72,LP72,LQ72,LR72,LS72,LT72,LU72,LV72,LW72,LX72,LY72,LZ72,MA72,MB72,MC72,MD72,ME72,MF72,MG72,MH72,MI72,MJ72,MK72,ML72,MM72,MN72,MO72,MP72,MQ72,MR72,MS72,MT72,MU72,MV72,MW72,MX72,MY72,MZ72,NA72,NB72,NC72,ND72,NE72,NF72,NG72,NH72,NI72,NJ72,NK72,NL72,NM72,NN72,NO72,NP72,NQ72,NR72,NS72,NT72,NU72,NV72,NW72,NX72,NY72,NZ72,OA72,OB72,OC72,OD72,OE72,OF72,OG72,OH72,OI72,OJ72,OK72,OL72,OM72,ON72,OO72,OP72,OQ72,OR72,OS72,OT72,OU72,OV72,OW72,OX72,OY72,OZ72,PA72,PB72,PC72,PD72,PE72,PF72,PG72,PH72,PI72,PJ72,PK72,PL72,PM72,PN72,PO72,PP72,PQ72,PR72,PS72,PT72,PU72,PV72,PW72,PX72,PY72,PZ72,QA72,QB72,QC72,QD72,QE72,QF72,QG72,QH72,QI72,QJ72,QK72,QL72,QM72,QN72,QO72,QP72,QQ72,QR72,QS72,QT72,QU72,QV72,QW72,QX72,QY72,QZ72,RA72,RB72,RC72,RD72,RE72,RF72,RG72,RH72,RI72,RJ72,RK72,RL72,RM72,RN72,RO72,RP72,RQ72,RR72,RS72,RT72,RU72,RV72,RW72,RX72,RY72,RZ72,SA72,SB72,SC72,SD72,SE72,SF72,SG72,SH72,SI72,SJ72,SK72,SL72,SM72,SN72, SO72,SP72,SQ72,SR72,SS72,ST72,SU72,SV72,SW72,SX72,SY72,SZ72,TA72,TB72,TC72,TD72,TE72,TF72,TG72,TH72,TI72,TJ72,TK72,TL72,TM72,TN72,TO72,TP72,TQ72,TR72,TS72,TT72,TU72,TV72,TW72,TX72,TY72,TZ72,UA72,UB72,UC72,UD72,UE72,UF72,UG72,UH72,UI72,UJ72,UK72,UL72,UM72,UN72,UO72,UP72,UQ72,UR72,US72,UT72,UU72,UV72,UW72,UX72,UY72,UZ72,VA72,VB72,VC72,VD72,VE72,VF72,VG72,VH72,VI72,VJ72,VK72,VL72,VM72,VN7,WW72,WX72,WY72,WZ72,XA72,XB72,XC72,XD72,XE72,XF72,XG72,XH72,XI72,XJ72,XK72,XL72,XM72,XN72,XO72,XP72,XQ72,XR72,XS72,XT72,XU72,XV72,XW72,XX72,XY72,XZ72,YA72,YB72,YC72,YD72,YE72,YF72,YG72,YH72,YI72,YJ72,YK72,YL72,YM72,YN72,YO72,YP72,YQ72,YR72,YS72,YT72,YU72,YV72,YW72,YX72,YY72,YZ72,ZA72,ZB72,ZC72,ZD72,ZE72,ZF72,ZG72,ZH72,ZI72,ZJ72,ZK72,ZL72,ZM72,ZN72,ZO72,ZP72,ZQ72,ZR72,ZS72,ZT72,ZU72,ZV72,ZW72,ZX72,ZY72,ZZ72"


    ' list all cell you wish to merge in the Trigger column.
    '   Like, 30 = 6 & 23 to mean, merge the values of cell
    '                              6 & 23 in cell 30
    '   (separating commas are imporant, spaces are not)
    Const Mergers As String = "78=10&129, 79=11&130, 80=12&131, 82=14&133, 83=15&134, 84=16&135, 85=17&136, 86=18&137"


    Dim Trigger() As String
    Dim t As Integer
    Dim R As Long, C As Long
    Dim Merger() As String, Sp() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Trigger = Split(Triggers, ",")
    For t = 0 To UBound(Trigger)
        If Target.Address = Range(Trim(Trigger(t))).Address Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            C = Target.Column
            Merger = Split(Mergers, ",")
            For i = 0 To UBound(Merger)
                Sp = Split(Merger(i), "=")
                R = val(Sp(0))
                Sp = Split(Sp(1), "&")
                Cells(R, C).Value = Cells(val(Sp(0)), C).Value & _
                                    " / " & _
                                    Cells(val(Sp(1)), C).Value
            Next i
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next t
End Sub
```